# Drop all strings that are a subset of another string in the same list

Tags: python, string, list, set

I'm working on a scraping project and for some reason on some paragraphs I get both the complete paragraph and also the same paragraph divided in segments. So, if the paragraph is "My house is green and. I like it.", I sometimes get:

```
["My house is green. I like it.", "My house is green.", "I like it."]
```

So, when I turn everything into text I will get that paragraph duplicated. Is there any way I can check which strings are a subset of other strings in a list?

My desired output in this case would be to be left only with `["My house is green. I like it."]`

Comment: Any chance you can just get the initial paragraph that's the one you want to keep while scraping and just not scrape the rest? (rather than trying to pro-process it?)

Comment: Why can't you simply use the first element in that list?

Comment: I'm also working on a way to do that. Maybe because I scraped all descendant I'm having this problem.

Comment: What would happen for instance if you picked up a strange string just containing the letter `e` - which would be a subset of a lot of things etc...

Comment: @Selcuk It's a list of several paragraphs, that don't always repeat themselves

Answer (score 0):

An efficient approach is to iterate through the list sorted by the lengths of phrases in reverse order, and add each possible sub-phrase to a set, so that you can use the set to efficiently check if the current phrase is a sub-phrase of a previous, longer phrase:

```
output = []
seen = set()
for phrase in sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True):
    words = tuple(phrase.split())
    if words not in seen:
        output.append(phrase)
    seen.update({words[i: i + n + 1] for n in range(len(words)) for i in range(len(words) - n)})
```

so that given:

```
l = ["My house is green. I like it.", "My house is green.", "I like it."]
```

`output` becomes:

```
['My house is green. I like it.']
```

Answer (score -1):

I would take the longest string out of the list like this:

```
arr = ["My house is green. I like it.", "My house is green.", "I like it."]
print(max(arr, key=len))
```

The longest string can't be a substring of the others by definition

Comment: The list is composed of multiple paragraphs.